# creating dropbox like folder icons using pyqt?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, icons, pyqt

Is there a way that i can add my own icon to the existing folder and file icon like in dropbox or in ubuntu one.. Not only to the folders, it adds it's own icon to whatever the files you put inside the dropbox folder.. Is there anyway that i can achieve the same effect using pyqt..

Your suggestions are much awaited.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't understand. Are you trying to add an icon to an "existing folder and file icon?" Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: Yes exactly like what you are saying.. http://i39.tinypic.com/16jo4nn.png .. sorry for not making clear enough..

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with PyQt. With python, though, you can `subprocess.call()` with this parameters:

```
gvfs-set-attribute '/path/to/file' -t stringv metadata::emblems default
```

Restart your filebrowser and you should see the changes applied.